# How to resolve the issues encountered when using the infercnvpy package to process scRNA-seq data?

Tags: python

(base) rita@python # /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/lsh/Desktop/python/scRNA/lv/py/infercnv
.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/lsh/Desktop/python/scRNA/lv/py/infercnv.py", line 12, in 
cnv.io.genomic_position_from_gtf(
File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/infercnvpy/io/_genepos.py", line 41, in genomic_position_from_gtf
gtf = gtfparse.read_gtf(
File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gtfparse/read_gtf.py", line 254, in read_gtf
result_df = parse_gtf_and_expand_attributes(
File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gtfparse/read_gtf.py", line 189, in parse_gtf_and_expand_attributes
df = parse_gtf(
File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gtfparse/read_gtf.py", line 155, in parse_gtf
df_lazy = parse_with_polars_lazy(
File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gtfparse/read_gtf.py", line 118, in parse_with_polars_lazy
df = polars.scan_csv(
TypeError: scan_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sep'

The following is the code I ran and the gencode.vM32.annotation.gtf file was downloaded from the GENCODE database.

```py
import scanpy as sc
import infercnvpy as cnv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import diopy
import os

adata = diopy.input.read_h5(file = "scRNA/lv/input/for.python.h5")

cnv.io.genomic_position_from_gtf(
    gtf_file='scRNA/lv/input/gencode.vM32.annotation.gtf',
    adata=adata,
    gtf_gene_id='gene_name',
    inplace=True)
```